# Sorting rows without showing sorting column

Tags: sql, sorting, db2

In the query shown below, I need to show the first column `N` sorting by the second column `priority`, without showing the latter.

```
with number (n, priority) as (
  select 1, 12 from sysibm.sysdummy1 -- recursive complex query
) 
select n, priority from number
union all 
select 5, 13 from sysibm.sysdummy1 -- complex query here
```

The expected result is:

```
   N
   -
   1
   5
```

I can't really modify the query (since the real one is quite complex) and was wondering if I could enclose it as a subquery or maybe use it as a CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery?

```
with number (n, priority) as (
  select 1, 12 from sysibm.sysdummy1 -- recursive complex query
) 
select n
from (select n, priority from number
      union all 
      select 5, 13 from sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) x
order by priority;
```

Comment: Great. I didn't realize before the `select` of a recursive `with` does NOT need to be written right after it (adjacent to it). In this solution you wrote it afterwards. You learn something new every day.